# What are the main difference between Personal access client and Password client in laravel passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am new to oAuth2 and laravel-passport, i don't fully understand the difference between getting access token using personal access client and password client. Your explanation would be highly appreciated. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 31):

First, Having a basic understanding of **OAuth** can wipe a little bit confusion. So, I'll suggest you to become familiar with general terminology. Some articles:

- [http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2/](https://web.archive.org/web/20210125202508/https://www.bubblecode.net/en/2016/01/22/understanding-oauth2/)
- https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/

***Now lets get back to your question!***

- `Personal Access Clients` who has `personal access tokens` are authorized to access your `Resource Server`. Personal access tokens are good for giving third party applications access to your API without requiring your user to input their credentials in a potentially untrusted client.
- On the other hand, `Password Grant Clients` are your clients and you'd use password grant for them, where it is `safe` for the users to provide their credentials manually. `password grant tokens` generate while users provide valid credentials. Its generally used for first party clients and should not be used by third party clients.

Comment: looks like in passport there is a third option that is not a `Personal Access Clients` and not a `Password Grant Clients`