# what is token name in createToken() in Laravel Passport?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I use laravel passport and I found this code for registering a user with laravel passport:

```
$user= User::create([
    'name' =>$request->name,
    'email'=>$request->email,
    'password'=>bcrypt($request->password)
]);

$access_token_example = $user->createToken('PassportExample@Section.io')->accessToken;
```

in laravel doc mention that we should pass the `token name` to `createToken` function but my question is:

I don't understand what is the usage of the token name?

we just need to produce a random token why should we give a name to it?

and another question is : what is the standard for the `token name`? should it be same text for all the users? can I use rand() function inside?

and the third question is: where we store the tokens? database? session?

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54275082/what-are-the-main-difference-between-personal-access-client-and-password-client . It does not answer this question but makes me inclined to say "it's just a name you can do whatever you want with it"

Answer (score 0):

may be you want to get access token instead of token name and other info.

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens in user model instead of use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens